# What is the reason behind IE11 long running script issues?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, internet-explorer-11

I wanted to understand why does the IE11 respond with a long running script issue and becomes unresponsive till some time.
Surprisingly, this happens randomly
eg. Let's say on page load I call an API which responds with a bookings.

CASE 1: When number of bookings are less than 10 , it works perfectly FINE....

CASE 2: When number of bookings are more than 10 , it encounters this long running script issue

[image: script issue ref image]

As per the suggested fixes for this issue I see only IE11 Browser browser configuration /system settings changes only Eg: https://appuals.com/long-running-script-ie11/ which can't be triggered on customer side.

Would be thankful if anyone provides some clarity on this issue and possible fixes apart from config changes!!

Comment: Some of ECMA standard dont support IE

Comment: IE is old and inefficient. Its script engine is years behind modern browsers. It wasn't even considered to be fast when it was first released. Also inevitably things have moved on and there are lots of features it doesn't support. Don't support it for any new code unless someone forces you at gunpoint - tell them to use Edge instead to view your application